# More efficient value selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been using react to create a select drop down menu that holds its values like so

```
 <Select
     style={{ width: "100%" }}
     name="contractarea"
     id="contractarea"
     value={contractArea || 5}
 <MenuItem value={10}>Reason 3</MenuItem>
 <MenuItem value={20}>Reason 3</MenuItem>
 <MenuItem value={30}>Reason 3</MenuItem>
  />
```

However to control this i use

```
{contractArea === 20 ? (

            <Typography component="h2" variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom>
              Example Text
            </Typography>
            <FormGroup row>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={handleCheckChange("checkedA")}
                    value="checkedA"
                    color="primary"
                    defaultChecked
                  />
                }
                label="Example"
              />
           ) : (

          <div />
        )}
```

However if i wanted to call another value i would need to repeat the conditional above again, I feel like this is redundant and could be made more efficient. Also I render out a blank div to satisfy the conditional statement, I need this to just render something invisible to the user

Comment: Please be more specific, what do you mean by 'if i wanted to call another value i would need to repeat the conditional above'?

Comment: A more react-ish way of handling an `if this render that else ignore` is `condition && render` (instead of your `condition ? render : ingoreDiv`)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an OR value for your contractArea

```
{contractArea === 20 || contractArea === 30 ? (

            <Typography component="h2" variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom>
              Example Text
            </Typography>
            <FormGroup row>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    onChange={handleCheckChange("checkedA")}
                    value="checkedA"
                    color="primary"
                    defaultChecked
                  />
                }
                label="Example"
              />
           ) : (

          <div />
        )}
```